# reading first 4 columns from a multiple text files (which might have unbalance number of columns by rows) in r

Tags: r, csv

I have the following like text (csv) files to read, where first four columns are of my interest but after that I have alot of  junk. I just want to read first four columns into R.

[image]

I want first four columns, so that output (csv opened in excel) would look like:

[image]

I could not paste the whole file nor attach it due to limitations of SO. Here is smaller example for workout:

```
type,latitude,longitude,name,link1,
W,43.075319,-89.386145,Mirch Masala,"<just link, jjksskkls  hskks > ","<just link, jjksskkls  hskks > "
W,43.07488,-89.390698,Himal Chuli Restaurant,"<just link, jjksskkls  hskks > ","<just link,  hskks , hsksks  > "
W,43.074887,-89.391011,Chautara Restaurant,"<just link,  hskks , hsksks  > ","<just link, jjksskkls  hskks > "
W,43.092866,-89.351587,Dobhan Restaurant,"<just link, jjksskkls  hskks > ","<just link, jjksskkls , ssjjs hskks > "
W,43.074746,-89.393137,State Street Cash Mart,"<just link, jjksskkls  hskks > ","<just link, jjksskkls , ssjjs hskks > "
W,43.072801,-89.395718,Dotty Dumplings Dowry,"<just link, jjksskkls ,    hskks > ","<just link, jjksskkls , ssjjs hskks > "
W,43.074744,-89.393046,Dobra Tea,"<just link, jjksskkls  hskks > ","<just link, jjksskkls , ssjjs hskks > "
W,43.076372,-89.380231,Hi-Madison,"<just link, jjksskkls  hskks > ","<just link, jjksskkls , ssjjs hskks > "
W,43.019624,-89.421822,Candlewood Suites Fitchburg,"<just link, jjksskkls , ssjjs hskks > ","<just link, jjksskkls , ssjjs hskks > "
W,43.08154,-89.524094,Holiday Inn Hotel & Suites Madison West,"<just link, jjksskkls 100  hskks > ","<just link, jjksskkls , ssjjs hskks > "
```

Any idea on just reading first four columns while importing into R ?

Comment: Do you want 4 lines, 4 columns or both?

Comment: 4 columns any number of lines

Comment: Please clarify that in your question (since the last question says "lines")

Comment: Is the file so big that loading it all in the first place is a problem (time or space)?

Comment: @flodel The file is big, but I am concerned requirement of table which need equal number of columns in each row

Comment: I think your question's title doesn't really reflect your problem, which is that your rows might not all be balanced.

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks for the answer, I corrected the heading to reflect this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments to your question, your title is somewhat misleading. Where you're running into problems is not knowing the exact number of columns your final `data.frame` would have.

From the `?read.table` help page:

> count.fields can be useful to determine problems with reading files which result in reports of incorrect record lengths

So, let's try a different answer.

First, let this represent your data:

```
"W",43.075319,-89.386145,"Mirch Masala","<J, K>"
"W",43.07488,-89.390698,"Himal Chuli Restaurant","<J, K>","<J, K>","<J, K>"
"W",43.074887,-89.391011,"Chautara Restaurant","<J, K>","<J, K>"
"W",43.092866,-89.351587,"Dobhan Restaurant","<J, K>","<J, K>","<J, K>","<J, K>"
"W",43.074746,-89.393137,"State Street Cash Mart","<J, K>"
"W",43.072801,-89.395718,"Dotty Dumplings Dowry"
```

(This next step won't be required from your side if this is already saved as a text or csv file, but for the sake of a minimal reproducible example...)

Write those lines to a text file to simulate the `read.table` process:

```
writeLines('"W",43.075319,-89.386145,"Mirch Masala","<J, K>"
"W",43.07488,-89.390698,"Himal Chuli Restaurant","<J, K>","<J, K>","<J, K>"
"W",43.074887,-89.391011,"Chautara Restaurant","<J, K>","<J, K>"
"W",43.092866,-89.351587,"Dobhan Restaurant","<J, K>","<J, K>","<J, K>","<J, K>"
"W",43.074746,-89.393137,"State Street Cash Mart","<J, K>"
"W",43.072801,-89.395718,"Dotty Dumplings Dowry"', "myRaggedFile.txt")
```

That will create a "ragged" file to be read in using `read.table` or `read.csv`. The trick, though, is to use `count.fields` to figure out how many columns the file should have.

```
dat <- read.csv("myRaggedFile.txt", header=FALSE, 
                col.names=1:max(count.fields("myRaggedFile.txt", sep=",")))
dat
#      X1       X2        X3                     X4     X5     X6     X7     X8
# 1     W 43.07532 -89.38614           Mirch Masala <J, K>                     
# 2     W 43.07488 -89.39070 Himal Chuli Restaurant <J, K> <J, K> <J, K>       
# 3     W 43.07489 -89.39101    Chautara Restaurant <J, K> <J, K>              
# 4     W 43.09287 -89.35159      Dobhan Restaurant <J, K> <J, K> <J, K> <J, K>
# 5     W 43.07475 -89.39314 State Street Cash Mart <J, K>                     
# 6     W 43.07280 -89.39572  Dotty Dumplings Dowry            
dat <- dat[1:4] # To keep just the first four columns
## Or, continuing with my original answer:
## read.csv("myRaggedFile.txt", header=FALSE, 
##          col.names=1:max(count.fields("myRaggedFile.txt", sep=",")))[1:4]
```

Comment: By the way, I don't honestly know if this is any more or less efficient than reading the files in first and dropping the unwanted columns once they are in R.

Comment: that's what you are doing though! Which is very acceptable if the file is not too big.

Comment: @flodel, that's what I thought I was doing, hence my comment. But I'm also off to cook dinner now, so I was being lazy and didn't want to research it ;)

Answer (score 0):

when you read in your file use something like:

fist4columns  <-  read.table("/file/path/filename.csv",  header=TRUE,  sep=",")[, c(1:4)]